# Is it possible to load the whole script from remote server and run it

Tags: reactjs, redux

I know there's a word called 'server rendering' in React.

However, is it possible to keep my client side code like this way

## client side

```
<html>
<script>
loadScript('https://remote_server_rendering_which_contains_whole_redux_project_code')
</script>
<html>
```

Is it possible to do so? any example?

Comment: What are you tried to achieve?

Comment: I'm writing chrome extension plugin with Redux. Don't wanna re-deploy every time and force users to update the plugin. Wanna let server to do the update directly.